# Using pywinauto, how do I get Text of static text object, given the handle of the parent dialog

Tags: python-2.7, childwindow, pywinauto

**1. My code:**

```
print ('##########')  
app = pywinauto.application.Application()  
window_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title = u'My Dialog Name')  
my_handle = window_handle[0]  
window = app.window_(handle = my_handle)  
for x in window.Children():  
    print ('Child %s' % x)  
print ('##########')
```

**Output:**
    ##########
    Child: < pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper object at 0x02C12890>
    Child: < pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.ButtonWrapper object at 0x02C12870>
    Child: < pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper object at 0x02C128B0>
    Child: < pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.StaticWrapper object at 0x02C128F0>
    ##########

I want the text of Child: pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.StaticWrapper object at 0x02C128F0>. To do so, I need the handle of that static text. I assume that I should be able to derive the handle to the static text from the parent dialog, but I have no idea how. I know that once I have the handle, I can just use window.Texts().

Apologies in advance for the formatting of my question, first timing it here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the help. I used the following method:

my_dialog_name = u'My Dialog Name'
text_result = app.my_dialog_name.Static3.Texts()

Comment: Good. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. It's considered polite on SO. You can press the check box under voting buttons (you can accept an answer even if you have no enough reputation to vote up).

Comment: Sorry, I had looked all over for some button that showed the answer was accepted yesterday. Finally found the checkmark today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try to locate your "Static" with pywinauto builtin name resolution? Let's say I have running Calculator application with text "78" on its result. I connect to the application and start looking for a "Static" element on "Calculator" dialog. Since I don't know the exact name I just try to guess it. I draw my debug outlines of different colors until I find the control I need. After I found the control I can easily read its text. (Read more in [pywinauto docs here](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/stable/HowTo.html#how-to-specify-a-control-on-a-dialog) about specifying controls on a dialog.)

```
In [1]: from pywinauto.application import Application

In [2]: app = Application()

In [3]: app.connect(path="calc.exe")
Out[3]: <pywinauto.application.Application at 0x54362b0>

In [4]: app.Calculator.Static.DrawOutline()
Out[4]: 

In [5]: app.Calculator.Static2.DrawOutline("red")
Out[5]

In [6]: app.Calculator.Static3.DrawOutline("blue")
Out[6]

In [7]: app.Calculator.Static3.Texts()
Out[7]: [u'78']
```